# How to get java to produce decimal points while dividing

Tags: java, decimal, calculator

I'm making a basic calculator where you can plus, times, divide and minus as i was experimenting to see if it worked i noticed that instead of 5 divided by being equal to 1.25 it only displayed 1.

Here's the code i use to handle the math problems:

```
if (box.getSelectedItem().equals(divide)){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Integer.parseInt(first.getText()) / Integer.parseInt(second.getText()), "Answer", -1);
    main(args);
}
```

Is there code that displays the decimal points as well?

Comment: Well if you're gonna use Integer, it'll truncate it down to an integer. Use a ```Double```.

Comment: No, do NOT use a `Double` or `double` to store a value on a calculator.  You'll run into all sorts of floating point issues.  Please learn to use the `BigDecimal` class.  Using `Double` or `double` is simply terrible advice for this kind of thing, although technically it might answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Integer,it is happening.
Use [Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) to preserve decimals.
In your case,use

```
Double.parseDouble(first.getText()) / Double.parseDouble(second.getText())
```

Comment: Right.  And 1 / 5 + 1 / 10 is WHAT exactly?

Comment: i dont understand what are you asking?

Comment: OK, well go ahead and develop a calculator using `Double` to store the numbers.  Then use your calculator to work out `1 / 5 + 1 / 10`. If you don't get the answer that you expected, then you can rethink whether this is a good idea,

Answer (score 1):

Integer division will give you Integer. Try using Double or BigDecimal data type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the casting

```
(double)parseInt(first.getText()) / (double)parseInt(second.getText())
```

Int/Int will give you an Integer. So you need to cast it to Double to get the result in decimal.

**EDIT:**

If you dont want to show decimal when the result is a whole number then you need to check it like this:

```
Double res = (double)parseInt(first.getText()) / (double)parseInt(second.getText())
 Integer x;
 if(res % 1 == 0)
 {
    x =  (int)res
 }
```

Comment: I tried it and it works but now if i do 6 divided by 6 it displays 1.0 would there be any way to fix that?

Comment: @Dragon4c3:- So what result you want when you divide 6/6?

Comment: It's underlined red throughout (int)res i tried adding a ';' but nothing happened

Comment: @Dragon4c3:- Sorry it was my mistake, updated that. It was because I was casting a double to Int and then storing it into double variable.

Comment: `parseDouble()` is not really "casting", you know. `(double)parseInt()` would be.

Comment: (int)res is underlined in red do i need to extend anything or??

Comment: And also with Intger x; is that meant to be Intger or Integer?

Comment: Anyway would you know how to fix the error or am i doing something wrong?